# heroku express sever error 503 "service unavailable"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, axios

I created a server on heroku (no DB) and all the GET requests work. However, I have a POST request from a different heroku domain which is failing with error: 503 "service unavailable"
Did anyone faced it before ?

the request

```
  let origin;
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    origin = "http://localhost:5000/form";
  }
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    origin = "https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/https://cool-exercise-server.herokuapp.com/form";
  }

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const response = await axios.post(origin, { value });
    setResults((results) => [...results, ...response.data]);
  };
```

The Error:

```
xhr.js:177 POST https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/https://cool-exercise-server.herokuapp.com/form 503 (Service Unavailable)
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 503
```

heroku logs --tail:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/form" host=cool-exercise.herokuapp.com request_id=96c6ae17-7c6c-4ca8-ba21-30b5ba76e8e8 fwd="46.116.249.110" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=36ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

backend request handler :

```
app.post("/form", (req, res) => {
  const { value } = req.body;
  fs.createReadStream(path.normalize(value))
    .pipe(csv({}))
    .on("data", (data) => results.push(data))
    .on("end", () => {
      res.send(mergeData(results));
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the post request handler in backend ?

Comment: just edited my post, the req handler is:
```
app.post("/form", (req, res) => {
  const { value } = req.body;
  fs.createReadStream(path.normalize(value))
    .pipe(csv({}))
    .on("data", (data) => results.push(data))
    .on("end", () => {
      res.send(mergeData(results));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue in my post request, was trying to reach a local file while the server is hosted in a VM on the clowd.